# Prove that $f: A \to B$ is surjective iff $\forall b \in B, ((A \times ${$b$}$) \cap G_f) \neq \emptyset $

Tags: functions, proof-verification

The question is as follows:

Given a function $f : A \mapsto B$, denote the graph of $f$ by $G_f$ where $G_f \subset A \times B$. Prove that $f$ is surjective iff $\forall b \in B,  ((A \times ${$b$}$) \cap G_f) \neq \emptyset  $

What I did was try to prove the contrapositive:

Suppose that $\exists b \in B :((A \times ${$b$}$) \cap G_f) = \emptyset$

$\iff$ $\forall a \in A$,  $b \neq f(a)$
$\iff$ $f$ is not surjective.

$\therefore$ $\exists b \in B :  ((A \times ${$b$}$) \cap G_f) = \emptyset \iff f$ is not surjective

$\therefore$ $\forall b \in B :  ((A \times ${$b$}$) \cap G_f) \neq \emptyset \iff f$ is surjective

However, this seems too simple and I have a feeling I have missed something. If anyone could check this method that'd be great. Also, if anyone has any interesting questions for practice on the topic of functions: bijections, surjections, injections, cardinality, counting finite sets etc then I'd benefit greatly from those.

Comment: It seems ok to me. In fact, the exrcise itself is almost tautological.

Comment: Your job is correct, and this exercize is actually very simple.

Comment: Yeah a lot of the ones in my book seem this way, which I just found a little odd

Comment: There are parentheses missing in the cartesian product.

Comment: The Q is simple & your A is ok. In Set Theory a function is defined to BE its graph, and the definition of "$f:A\to B$" is surjective" is "$\forall b\in B\;\exists a\in A\;((a,b)\in f ).$"

Answer (score 2):

The main exercise is to give a proof with minimal notation.:)
$$
(A \times \{b\}) \cap G_{f} = \mbox{the pre-image of $b$ under $f$}.
$$
By definition $f$ is surfjective if this pre-image is nonempty for every $b$.

Comment: So is my proof not OK?

Comment: Your proof is correct, but it will greatly help your mathematical growth to prefer prose to notation.

Comment: @avs You mean logical symbols. There are many types of notation (I get what you're saying, and I agree, but the way you phrase it is confusing).

Comment: No, I meant notation in general.  As few symbols as possible.

Answer (score 0):

It' still simpler than you think if you observe that 
$$\operatorname{pr}_A\bigl((A\times\{b\})\cap G_f \bigr)=\operatorname{pr}_A\bigl(f^{-1}(b)\bigr)=\{ a\in A\mid f(a)=b\},$$
where $\operatorname{pr}_A$ denotes the projection from $A\times B$ onto the first factor.